Ethereum (Istanbul, PoA private network) automated contract deployment and interactions
Heres my contract deployer:
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const { fstat } = require('fs');
const fs = require('fs');

// Define the ABI and bytecode of the contract
const abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "retrieve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "num",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "store",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
];
const bytecode = '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';

async function deployContract() {
    // Connect to Ethereum network
    const provider = new ethers.getDefaultProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8546');
    const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('pk.txt', 'utf8');
    const signer = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
    // Define the factory for the contract
    const contractFactory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer);

    // Deploy the contract
    const deployedContract = await contractFactory.deploy({gasPrice: 0});

    // Wait for the deployment transaction to be mined
    //await deployedContract.waitForDeployment();

    // Print contract address
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync('addr.txt', deployedContract.target);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    console.log('Contract deployed at address:', deployedContract.target);
}

deployContract().catch(console.error);


heres my contract data storer:
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const fs = require('fs');

// ABI of the smart contract
const abi =  [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "retrieve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "num",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "store",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
];
async function storeValue(contractAddress, valueToStore, privateKey) {
    // Connect to a provider (like Infura)
    const provider = new ethers.getDefaultProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8546");

    // Connect to the wallet
    const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

    // Connect to the contract
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, wallet);

    try {
        // Call the store function
        const tx = await contract.store(valueToStore, { gasPrice: 0 });
        console.log(tx);
        console.log('Value stored successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error storing value:', error);
    }
}

// Replace '<YOUR_INFURA_PROJECT_ID>' with your actual Infura project ID
const contractAddress = fs.readFileSync("addr.txt", "utf8");
const valueToStore = fs.readFileSync("numdata.txt", "utf8");; // Replace with the value you want to store
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("pk.txt", "utf8"); // Replace with your private key
storeValue(contractAddress, valueToStore, privateKey).catch(err => console.error(err));


and this is my data retreiver:
const { ethers } = require('ethers');
const fs = require('fs');

// Define your private key
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync("pk.txt", "utf8");

// Initialize provider and wallet
const provider = new ethers.getDefaultProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8546");
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);

// Define the ABI of the smart contract
const abi = [
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "retrieve",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "num",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "store",
        "outputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    }
];

// Read contract address from file
//const contractAddress = fs.readFileSync('address.txt', 'utf8').trim();
const contractAddress = fs.readFileSync("addr.txt", "utf8");
async function retrieveValue(contractAddress) {
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);

    try {
        // Call the retrieve function
        const value = await contract.retrieve();
        console.log('Retrieved value:', value);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error calling retrieve function:', error);
    }
}

// Call the function to retrieve value from the contract
retrieveValue(contractAddress).catch(err => console.error(err));


I am getting this error:
code: 'BAD_DATA',
  value: '0x',
  info: { method: 'retrieve', signature: 'retrieve()' },
  shortMessage: 'could not decode result data'

If this looks familiar or clearly see my error it would be appreciated if you could let me know. This is running on a local legacy private network it should align with Istanbul Ethereum standards.

Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76607233/error-could-not-decode-result-data-value-0x-info-method-getcreatorcou

I strongly advice against hard coded abi simply because it's very hard to find what could be wrong.
It could be the order, a type, or any slight difference that will change the bytecode.
Ideally, compile the contract and generate the ABI using ethers or solc.
You can then validate the bytecode and also validate that your contract is working as expected.
Then use the ABI and bytecode generated by ethers or solc in your method without altering them.
